# Como imprimir una variable de un arreglo de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objeto

Al realizar console.log(file);
tengo la siguiente respuesta:

```
File {upload: {…}, status: 'queued', previewElement: li.list-group-item, previewTemplate: li.list-group-item, accepted: true, …}
accepted: true
dataURL: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA+g
height: 1000
previewElement: li.list-group-item.dz-processing.dz-image-preview.dz-success.dz-complete
previewTemplate: li.list-group-item.dz-processing.dz-image-preview.dz-success.dz-complete
processing: true
status: "success"
upload: {uuid: 'e1d3681d-e61e-4c88-853a-c0b2cd58fc50', progress: 100, total: 125388, bytesSent: 125388, filename: 'Peril PHP.png', …}
width: 1000
xhr: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 30000, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
lastModified: 1635721013154
lastModifiedDate: Sun Oct 31 2021 16:56:53 GMT-0600 (hora estándar central) {}
name: "Peril PHP.png"
size: 125202
type: "image/png"
webkitRelativePath: ""
[[Prototype]]: File
```

Lo que necesito es, imprimir el valor de "dataURL" ....
he intentado esto:

```
alert(file.dataURL);
alert(file[0].dataURL);
alert(file.File.dataURL);
```

Incluso intente:

```
$.each( file, function( key, value ) {
  alert( key + ": " + value ); 
});
```

Sin embargo, en el último caso el each me da los otros resultados donde status es "queued"

Comment: Coloca tu log en código y no en imagen

Comment: ok, ya quedo :)

Comment: Ese log esta raro, puedes colocar tu arreglo aca https://jsfiddle.net/ para verificar y te ayudemos mejor, porque el que colocas no tiene estructura de arreglo.

Answer (score 0):

resulta que he logrado mi cometido... investigue un poco más  la forma correcta de obtener el base64 de la imagen es la siguiente:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);

reader.onload = function () {
   console.log(reader.result);
};
reader.onerror = function (error) {
   console.log('Error: ', error);
};
```